# Push index array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm sure there's a word for what I,m looking for but since I don't know it I can't find the answear to my problem, what I have is a jagged array of double and I want the value at index 0 to be the value of index 1 same for the index 1 going to the 2 until the end of the array and the last index being pish to the index 0

Example :

***Original***

`private double[][] array = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, ...}`

***Become (After the modification)*** 
I know it's seems I'm redeclaring the array that's not the point, it's just to show you what it should be after.

`private double[][] array = { {4, 1, 2, 3}, {8, 5, 6, 7}, ...}`

***EDIT***

If you know the word or somethings about what I'm looking for, could you say so in the comment I will delete the question and look further into it

Comment: A missclick I guess, sorry

Comment: That is usually referred to as rotation. I don't believe that capability is built into arrays. How about using queues instead of arrays?

Comment: Never used queues, but if I do so I need to be able to fill them with linq, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually called rotating. You can achieve it a `for`-loop, but note that since your rotating to the right, it's easier to work your way from back to front, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var len = array[i].Length;
    if (len > 1) {
        var last = array[i][len - 1];
        for(var j = len - 1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            array[i][j] = array[i][j - 1];
        }
        array[i][0] = last;
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to go right  ???, I guess so, I will just do the for loop manually to get it

Comment: @Mokmeuh Yes, you can rotate in either direction. You just have to reverse the direction of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a `List` of `Queue` instead of a jagged array. Below an example of how your jagged array could look like and how to move elements:

```
var queues = new List<Queue<double>>();

//first queue (1,2,3,4)
var queue = new Queue<double>();
queue.Enqueue(4);
queue.Enqueue(3);
queue.Enqueue(2);
queue.Enqueue(1);
queues.Add(queue);

//second queue (5,6,7,8)
var queue2 = new Queue<double>();
queue.Enqueue(8);
queue.Enqueue(7);
queue.Enqueue(6);
queue.Enqueue(5);
queues.Add(queue2);

//an example of how to "rotate"
var lastItem = queues[0].Dequeue(); // (1,2,3)
queues[0].Enqueue(lastItem); // (4,1,2,3)
```